# Method returning early, not completing

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

This method never gets past the foreach loop. No matter what I place after it, it doesn't get ran. Even if the book object had no contact objects in it, it shouldn't just skip the rest of the code. This is being used for a contact selector in an app i'm working on, any ideas on what's going on here? Thanks

```
public class UserContactService : IUserContactService
{
    public List<Contact> GetContacts()
    {
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        var book = new Xamarin.Contacts.AddressBook();
        Console.WriteLine("Before loop");
        foreach (Contact c in book)
        {
            contacts.Add(c);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        return contacts;
    }
}
```

Comment: use try and catch, to check whether there is exception or not.

Comment: Have you stepped through the code to make sure the foreach is running?
You're missing a check for permissions, are you sure your app is allowing you permissions to check the addressbook?

Comment: obviously if 'book' has a count of 0, then the foreach won't run. So as the others have suggested you need to breakpoint just after "var book = new Xamarin.Contacts.AddressBook();" and see if 'book' has a value etc.

Comment: yeah there's an exception with the foreach. do you know if there's some permission that i'm missing to use xamarin contacts? Everything i'm finding is looking like I'm going to have to do a big rewrite for it

Comment: you need to catch exception brother, like in catch(exception exc){  throw exc;}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With Xamarin, you need to check that the user has granted permissions to access the contact book first, otherwise your foreach is going to error (because book will never contain contacts).

To get permissions from the app user, you can do that within Xamarin too:

```
if (!await book.RequestPermission()) {
    Console.WriteLine("Permission denied by user or manifest");
    return;
}
```

I'd also wrap your foreach in a try/catch for additional error messaging etc:

```
try {      
    foreach (Contact c in book)
    {
        contacts.Add(c);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

More info on Xmarin Mobile here: https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.mobile